Making a bracha mentally in case of doubt
Normally, in cases where the necessity of a bracha is in doubt, we say safek brachos lehakel—skip the bracha rather than risk making one in vain. But there are opinions that you can make a bracha mentally in cases where you're unable to make one verbally. Does anyone recommend doing so in case of a safek? Or could it still be considered a bracha levatala?

There's another way of dealing with the situation - that is using the preface of 'בריך רחמנא מרא מלכא דעלמא' instead of the normal preface. See the Oruch haShulchan .

In two places (Yabia Omer 9 O.C 98:10, Yabia Omer 4 O.C 2:12) Rav Ovadia quotes many Achronim who say that there is no bracha levatala if one makes a bracha mentally.
As to if this is recommended, Rav Ovadia cites the Kaf Hachaim (O.C 174 Seif Katan 49, O.C 184 Seif Katan 22, O.C 185 Seif Katan 5) that one should mentally say the bracha in a case of a safek. He also quotes the Ben Ish Chai (Vayeshev 6 and 12, Achrei Mot/Kedoshim 13, etc) who says the same. And it's only because of Midat Chasidut.
